# Phase shifting in frequency domain

Tags: fft, audio, frequency-spectrum, analytic-signal

I am aware this topic has already been addressed in at least one question here, but despite that I could not find the solution to my problem.
Also bear patience with me since I am not a mathematics guru but a coder, so I am not really able to explain my problem with formulas but I will try to expose it to my best anyway.

Suppose I have the FFT spectrum of a real audio signal and I want to carry phase shift by a constant amount s by multiplying all spectrum bins by $k= e^{js}$.
The matter turns out more complex than expected,  because the full complex spectrum of a real signal is composed of the signal spectrum summed with its mirrored conjugate,  therefore any attempt at multiplying as described above (despite taking care to multiply the negative frequencies by $-k$) will produce a time domain signal with distortions close to the beginning and end of frame (using Hann windowed signals can mask the error but that is not a good solution for me, it is like hiding dust under the carpet).
This happens simply because $k(Z+z^{*})$,  what one actually gets, is not the same as $kZ + (kz)^{*}$,  what instead it should be,  where $z$ is the mirrored spectrum.

After studying and experimenting,  I understood that the only way is starting with a spectrum WITHOUT conjugates added. For example,  such a spectrum for a pure frequency would contain the whole peak body for that frequency as a simple asinc function from $0$ to $z-1$ (where $z$ is the frame size)  without any mirrored conjugate added. That way you can actually carry phase shift by multiplying the whole spectrum by $k$ to then add it with its mirrored conjugate and convert back to time domain,  and the result is a perfect phase shifted signal (tested).

Unfortunately you cannot get rid of the mirrored conjugates,  because once two things are added you can' t separate them anymore.
The only way to obtain such a spectrum devoid of mirrored conjugates added,  is feeding the FFT with a complex signal,  where real and imaginary parts are in quadrature. That is trivial when it is about supplying pure frequencies,  as one has just to feed with a complex sinusoid,  but WHAT to do with a plain audio signal? One would have to supply a $\frac{\pi}{2}$ shifted version for the imaginary part,  which is something I can' t do because I cannot phase shift to start with (circular problem)!
Can you help me ?  My brain is stopping...

For completeness I must add that to carry frequency shift in spectral domain (getting rid of the "twin" sideband of course) the *same* problem arises: one has to perform spectral shifting (by multiplying by twiddle factors either switching to cepstral or back to time domain) on a spectrum devoid of its mirrored conjugate added,  otherwise edge distortions would result in the time domain signal for obvious reasons.

How to obtain such a spectrum devoid of conjugates starting from a real audio signal then ?

The picture below shows the distortion more noticeable at the edges of shifting the phase of a pure frequency by multiplying positive and negatives frequencies by k and -k respectively as many authors suggest

[image: The distorced result of a sinewave frequency-shifted by multiplying the pos frequencies by k and the negative ones by -k]

TO REFORMULATE MY QUESTION:
which is the least cpu intensive approach to convert the fft spectrum of a real signal to the spectrum of an analytic signal ?

UPDATE:
I understood the problem by a different perspective.
Even the very act of multiplying a spectrum by a phasor to operate phase shift is indeed a multiplication,  implying a circular convolution in time domain,  which therefore will always produce edge artifacts unless working with integer frequencies. Therefore,  even an apparently simple thing as phase shifting a spectral frame requires an overlap/save scheme or alike as used for actual filtering.
I tried this approach and works as expected indeed.
In addition,  by shifting this way by PI/2 and merging the original spectral frames with the shifted versions to form a complex spectrum,  you end up with an analytic spectrum devoid of negative frequencies,  on which one can carry operations like precise frequency shifting or peak analysis much better and more accurately than when working on a non analytic spectrum. The only drawback is the complexity and relative cpu load of the whole process,  but apparently no simpler solutions exist

Comment: HI Elena- It looks like you are understanding a lot of the aspects including the mathematics. Can I ask what in the end you are trying to accomplish? I hear that you are dealing with audio signals, what is it exactly you want to do with the audio signals (just in case your question as written is already down the wrong path to do what you really want to accomplish).

Comment: I am the author of the spectral modules for Synth Edit. It is a quite advanced modular spectral framework. Recently I realized the issues above described i.e that to carry certain spectral operations in a mathematically accurate way,  you would better work on an Analytical spectrum devoid of the mirrored negative frequencies conjugated overimposed. In addition I found much disinformation on the web. Many authors seem not even aware of the problem described above and still insist that multiplying the left side by k and the right side by -k is enough. That is not true,  it is just an approx!

Comment: Yes I have come across this very thing in particular with implementing time delays with FFT's where if the construction of the conjugate was not carefully done an actual frequency offset could be imposed (where the time delay is time varying). So I think I understand what you are touching on!

Comment: Do you need to do a frequency domain based time delay (vs time domain approaches)? What I had actually found was that if I didn't reverse the positive frequencies and conjugate the phase to create the negative frequencies (but computed the negative frequencies directly using the expected linear phase translation) that a frequency offset could be induced

Comment: Can you also show the simplified code of what you are trying to do and what the problem is? The $\pi/2$ shifted version if that is the solution is the Hilbert Transform which is quite feasible to do in the time domain if the relative bandwidth is narrow enough. Not sure that is necessary which comes back to what is it you want in the end--- are you simply trying to time delay the audio signals? Have you consider time domain approaches to doing this?

Comment: Yep spectra can be really tricky, more than I expected at beginning! One solution for me could be implementing an actual overlap-save scheme just to carry a linear convolution with a Hilbert function but to me it sounds quite stupid... only to have an analytical spectrum! Is is possible that there aren' t any mathematics tricks or shortcuts to avoid that ?  Seems crazy...

Comment: I am still trying to understand what is it you are trying to do? Delay the signal in time?

Comment: No,  no delays. For that I would simply use zero pad and overlap and multiply the spectrum by twiddle factors. I need an analytical spectrum from either a real signal or from its spectrum. I now understood I have to pass forcibly thru a Hilbert transform. But doing that in time domain means convolving which is quite cpu expensive... or is there another way ?

Comment: I was just trying to shift signal phase by a constant amount, .so that all its cosines constituting it have phase shifted by a same amount. No delays

Comment: Ok so your question above really boils down to: "Here is my signal: (a description of your signal as in its minimum to maximum bandwidth would be good), I need to create an analytic signal. What is the least CPU intensive approach?"    If you change your question to that I think you will get the answer you are looking for (no need to explain how to approach it from frequency or time domain etc..you just want to know how to do it the simplest and let the responders detail their appraoch in either domain) Just a suggestion ;)

Comment: So if we let $f(X(\omega))$ be whatever you're doing in the frequency domain, are you just doing $x_{shifted}(t) = \mathrm{ifft}(f(\mathrm{fft}(x_{unshifted}(t)))$?  Because if you are, you're always going to have end effects, and not because your particular $f(X(\omega))$ is trying to accomplish phase shifts.

Comment: @dan:  i reformulated my question at the end

Comment: @elena ca you add a description of your signal as in its minimum to maximum bandwidth and sample rate?